# PowerToys : command not find unable

Tags: system, power-toys

## System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process 'pwsh.exe' with working directory 'C:\Users\29711\AppData\Local\PowerToys'. 系统找不到指定的文件。

at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.PowerToys.Settings.UI.ViewModels.CmdNotFoundViewModel.RunPowerShellScript(String powershellExecutable, String powershellArguments, Boolean hidePowerShellWindow)

## How to find the file.Perhaps,Chinese Path?

[How to find the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVNLp.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.